# Partitions of an integer into elements of a set

Tags: python, function

I want to define a function, which, when given a set (of positive integers) and an integer, returns the number of partitions of that integer into elements of the set. For example,

```
partitions({1,2,3},5)=5
```

Since `1+1+1+1+1=5`, `1+1+1+2=5`, `1+2+2=5`, `1+1+3=5`, and `2+3=5`.

What would be the most efficient way of implementing this in Python?

Note: It doesn't need to return the actual partitions, just the number of them.

Comment: Dynamic programming... like the subset sum problem.

Comment: But that being said, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: And are the numbers guaranteed to be positive and integral?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that. I tried a more brute-force method but couldn't figure out how to avoid double counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the values are **integral** and **positive** (so in the set `{1, 2, 3, ...}`) We can use a *dynamic programming approach* here:

```
import numpy as np

def count_subsetsum(xs : set, s : int):
    v = np.zeros(s+1, dtype=int)
    v[0] = 1
    for x in xs:
        b = np.zeros(s+1, dtype=int)
        b[:] = v[:]
        for d in range(x,s+1,x):
            b[d:] += v[:s-d+1]
        v = b
    return v[s]
```

Here we thus consider a vector `v`. Initially the vector contains only zeros, except for `v[0]` that is equal to `1` (since we can construct exactly one sum with a total of zero: considering no elements at all).

Now we will update the vector. We will fetch a value `x` from the iterable `xs`, and we will "sum up the vector". We do this by iteratively adding `v[:s-d+1]` to the end of the vector `b`. `v[:s-d+1]` contains all elements up to (and excluding) `s-d-1`. We add this to `b[d:]`. So the value of `v[i]` is added to `b[i+d]` for all the elements in the vector. We do this for `d` in every multiple of `x`. So the first upgrade we virtually "add one `x`" to every element in `v`. The second time, we "add a two `x`s" to every sum we already constructed.

We do this for every `x` in `xs`, and at the end `v[s]` thus contains all ways we can construct a sum that sums up to `s`. So we return that `v[s]`.

For example:

```
>>> count_subsetsum({1,2,3},5)
5  # 1+1+1+1+1 1+1+1+2 1+1+3 1+2+2 2+3
>>> count_subsetsum({1,2},5)
3  # 1+1+1+1+1 1+1+1+2 1+2+2
>>> count_subsetsum({1,3},5)
2  # 1+1+1+1+1 1+1+3
>>> count_subsetsum({1,3,5},5)
3  # 1+1+1+1+1 1+1+3 5
>>> count_subsetsum({1,2,4},5)
4  # 1+1+1+1+1 1+1+1+2 1+2+2 1+4
>>> count_subsetsum({1},5)
1  # 1+1+1+1+1
```

(I added a comment with the sums for every example)

The advantage of using a dynamic programming approach over a brute force approach is that it does not scale exponentially. Take for instance the following query:

```
>>> count_subsetsum({1,2,5,7,22},15921)
1746490921624
```

That is 1'746'490'921'624. Even if we manage to generate a billion results per second, it would still take 1'746 seconds (which is roughly half an hour). So usually counting is faster than enumerating.